# Can we define the projective norm on any algebraic tensor product of normed vector spaces.

Tags: banach-spaces, tensor-products

So I read a little out of Ryan's "Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces" and in chapter 1, the author identified the algebraic tensor product of normed vector spaces $X$ and $Y$, which I will denote by $X \otimes^{\text{alg}}Y$ with a subspace of the dual space of the bounded bilinear functionals on $X \times Y$ $L(X, Y; \mathbb{C})^*$ by defining $x \otimes y (A) = A(x,y)$. Then in chapter 2, the author defined the projective norm on $X \otimes^{\text{alg}}Y $, denoted $\|\cdot \|_{\pi}:X \otimes^{\text{alg}} Y \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ by $$\|u\|_{\pi} = \inf \bigg \{ \sum_{j=1}^n \|x_j\| \|y_j\|: (x_j)_{j=1}^n \subset X \text{, }  (y_j)_{j=1}^n \subset Y \text{ and } u = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \otimes y_j  \bigg \}$$

**Question:** Can define this projective norm on the algebraic tensor product of two normed vector spaces without identifying it with a subspace of the dual space of the bounded bilinear functionals on $X \times Y$ and instead just using the universal property of the algebraic tensor product and the norm definition, and maybe some Hahn-Banach argument or something?

I have been wrestling with this for a week and the only issue is showing that $\|
u\| = 0$ implies that $u =0$. I can show that $\|
u\| = 0$ implies that for each $\phi \in X^*, \psi \in Y^*$, the bounded bilinear functional $T_{\phi, \psi} \in L(X, Y; \mathbb{C})$ defined by $T_{\phi, \psi}(x,y) = \phi(x)\psi(y)$ satisfies $T_{\phi, \psi}(u) = 0$.